# Chess Engine in C# - bad moves

Tags: c#, logic, chess

I am currently trying myself on programming a chess engine. I wrote a simple AlphaBeta Minimax and MaterialBalance Evaluation (linked below). I am using SebLagues Chess Challenge Project to program my chess engine (https://github.com/SebLague/Chess-Challenge). The problem i face is that, with a depth of 4 my engine is not able to foresee a simple checkmate, which should be foreseeable with a depth of 4. I cant find the mistake so i thought more eyepairs could help.

The bot just plays weird moves. The evaluation function returns positive values if white is winning and negative values if black ist winning (as intended) but the bot just sacrifices figures all over, so i think its something inside search class or Think method

PS:I am doing this for myself so i dont have the boundaries given in the challenge (thats why i made several classes etc)

Main class:

```
public class TRACER : IChessBot
{
    //Constant Variables
    private const int DEPTH = 4; //Search depth

    //Used classes
    Search findMove = new Search();

    public Move Think(Board board, Timer timer)
    {
        //Variables
        int moveScore; //Score a certain move has
        int bestScore = int.MinValue; //Score of the current best move (low value on start to guarantee update)
        int nodeSearched = 0; //Number of nodes searched
        Move bestMove; //Current best move to be played

        //Generate all legal possible moves
        Move[] moves = board.GetLegalMoves();
        bestMove = moves[0];

        foreach (Move currentMove in moves)
        {
            //for every move -> make move virtually and evaluate how good it is
            board.MakeMove(currentMove);
            moveScore = findMove.MiniMaxAB(board, DEPTH, int.MinValue, int.MaxValue, board.IsWhiteToMove);
            board.UndoMove(currentMove);

            //if the score of this move is better than the current best -> switch
            if (moveScore > bestScore) 
            {
                bestScore = moveScore;
                bestMove = currentMove;
            }
            nodeSearched++;
            Debug.WriteLine("currentMove:{0} | moveScore:{1}", currentMove, moveScore);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("---- bestMove:{0} | bestScore:{1} ----", bestMove, bestScore);
        return bestMove;
    }
}
```

Search class:

```
namespace Chess_Challenge.src.TRACER
{
    internal class Search
    {
        //used Classes
        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation();

        //NegaMax AlphaBeta Pruning Algorith -> returns a high value for the current play (regardless of colour)
        public int MiniMaxAB(Board board, int depth, int alpha, int beta, bool maximizingPlayer)
        {
            //Variables
            int moveScore; //score of the current move

            //if depth is reached then evaluate position
            if (depth == 0)
                return eval.EvaluatePosition(board) * (maximizingPlayer ? -1 : 1);
            //if player is checkmated return low value (bad for white) or high value (bad for black)
            if (board.IsInCheckmate())
                return board.IsWhiteToMove ? int.MinValue : int.MaxValue;
            //if game is a draw return equal
            if (board.IsDraw())
                return 0;

            //Get all legal moves
            Move[] moves = board.GetLegalMoves();
        
            //for every legal move get the best move for black and white
            if (maximizingPlayer)
            {
                moveScore = int.MinValue;
                foreach (Move move in moves)
                {
                    board.MakeMove(move);
                    moveScore = MiniMaxAB(board, depth - 1, alpha, beta, !maximizingPlayer);
                    board.UndoMove(move);

                    alpha = Math.Max(alpha, moveScore);
                    if (beta <= alpha)
                        break;
                }
                return moveScore;
            }

            else
            {
                moveScore = int.MaxValue;
                foreach (Move move in moves)
                {
                    board.MakeMove(move);
                    moveScore = MiniMaxAB(board, depth - 1, alpha, beta, !maximizingPlayer);
                    board.UndoMove(move);

                    beta = Math.Min(beta, moveScore);
                    if (beta <= alpha)
                        break;
                }
                return moveScore;
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Evaluation class:

```
namespace Chess_Challenge.src.TRACER
{
    internal class Evaluation
    {
        // Piece values:                                .,   P,   K,   B,   R,   Q,      K
        private static readonly int[] mgPieceValues = { 0,  80, 335, 363, 460, 940, 100000};
        private static readonly int[] egPieceValues = { 0, 100, 305, 333, 563, 950, 100000};

        //Endgame Transition
        private int egT(Board board)
        {
            return BitOperations.PopCount(board.AllPiecesBitboard);
        }
        //Get the value of a single piece regarding all parameters .TODO

        public int EvaluatePosition(Board board)
        {
            int whiteMaterial = 0;
            int blackMaterial = 0;

            for (PieceType pieceType = PieceType.Pawn; pieceType <= PieceType.King; pieceType++)
            {
                whiteMaterial += mgPieceValues[(int)pieceType] * BitOperations.PopCount(board.GetPieceBitboard(pieceType, true));
                blackMaterial += mgPieceValues[(int)pieceType] * BitOperations.PopCount(board.GetPieceBitboard(pieceType, false));
            }

            return whiteMaterial - blackMaterial;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the material balance works and i think its something inside the search function which i did not find. Or maybe its just some logical error in my brain.

[The picture where the engine decides to not protect pawn instead sliding rook][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4jQD.png

Comment: What's the code of `IsInCheckmate` and what's the final position where the checkmate occurs in the variation?

Comment: IsInCheckmate just checks if a position is checkmate - maybe i need to switch values then, but the thing is that the Engine play particular bad in odd depth and when playing black

Comment: But the problem is that a checkmate is not being properly detected. So the first place I would look at is `IsInCheckmate` and I would keep in mind what the actual checkmate position is. Either that method is not working properly, or the method is not being called properly. Either way, this method and the actual chess position should be our point of departure.

Comment: https://github.com/Sp3ctr402/Chess-Challenge- imo it works and is called properly but you can have a look yourself if you want to

Comment: Please paste the link to the exact location of the method. I will be happy to look into it. Also, please provide the specification for the position whose mate was not properly detected.

Comment: r1bqkbnr/pppp1ppp/n7/4p3/2B1P3/5Q2/PPPP1PPP/RNB1K1NR b KQkq - 0 1 - this is the position, obviously the pawn in front of bishop needs to move or gets protected which the engine doesnt do on its move (engine is black)

https://github.com/Sp3ctr402/Chess-Challenge-/tree/master/Chess-Challenge/src - inside the TRACER Folder you will find the Search, Evaluation and Main (TRACER) Method.

You can set custom FEN positions by replacing line 96 in (https://github.com/Sp3ctr402/Chess-Challenge-/blob/master/Chess-Challenge/src/Framework/Application/Core/ChallengeController.cs)

Comment: with board.LoadPosition("FEN-String") if you want to test other positions

Comment: regarding the position - the engine doesnt move or protect the pawn (mostly slides the rook) so i mate it by taking the pawn with the queen. With a depth of 4 i suppose the engine should see this and dont move down that game path, but it doesnt

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you also provide a screenshot of this position?

Comment: Yes i edit the question, its in the link since i dont have enough reputation to embed pictures

Comment: Thanks. So mate in 1 is threatened on f7 and the function does not detect it. I presume the game went 1. e4 e5 2. Bc4 Na6 3. Qf3. Is this the game position or is the comp calculating at an earlier stage?

Comment: This is the position its played into and in that position the engine decides to play rook to b8 instead of knight to h6 or pawn to f6 so it doesnt detect the checkmate

Answer (score 2):

I think swapping the order of these two calls will go a long way to resolving your issues with it missing mate in N's. It doesn't matter how much extra material you have if the opponent's last move has checkmated you!

```
if (board.IsInCheckmate())
        return board.IsWhiteToMove ? int.MinValue : int.MaxValue;

if (depth == 0)
         return eval.EvaluatePosition(board) * (maximizingPlayer ? -1 : 1);
        //if player is checkmated return low value (bad for white) or high value (bad for black)
```

I haven't tried these particular test positions but they look about right for the stage of testing that you are at right now. GIT hub [Chess test positions](https://gist.github.com/peterellisjones/8c46c28141c162d1d8a0f0badbc9cff9).

You will need to write a routine to load FEN board descriptions but it provides a good way to set up test positions and find bugs. You can also then design your own tests to check that your program does the right things.

I can't find the ones that I use online any more but they would probably be a bit too hard. They are actually a set of test positions in FEN notation for beginner humans with mates 1,2,3,4,.. getting progressively harder (with answers).

Comment: I actually can set specific FEN positions